# libc++ vs libstdc++ - breaks my application

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile my project on macos with the new c++11 features enabled and while the compilation is successful the program crashes.

It looks like there are some access violations but everything works on linux with libstdc++.

What can cause this errors?
I am not using any precompiled headers and the access violation can happen on standard library list and vectors...

Comment: Sounds like undefined behavior, maybe a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can cause this errors?

A logical error, that invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

That means that there is something in your code that does something it shouldn't do (it's a segmentation fault), which is not visible in your machine, but is on the other machine.

Been there, done that!